# How can I stop my app from crashing when subscribing to NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a working app that's almost done. Now when I run it on the simulator and go to hardware -> home in order to click on the app again, the app opens up on the VC I left and not the VC I set as my initial VC. I've tried to find a solution (the code below) but when I run it, click on hardware -> home and click on the app again, it crashes with an error of type ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to get popped view controller.'*** I'm new to programming and really don't understand what's going on here. My goal was to make it so that the app opens back on the VC I set to initialVC on my storyboard. Thanks for your help guys!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"appWillResignActive", name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)   

}

func appWillResignActive() -> () {

//As Ian MacDonald said, I created an instance of the view controller I want to show and used that instance in my popToViewController function.

    var mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    var controller: ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as ViewController

    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controller, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to pop to a brand new instance of `ViewController`. This crash has nothing to do with `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: What does this imply?

Comment: It implies that you need to find a reference to the instance of the `ViewController` that you want to pop to and use that instead.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll try to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Visualize the view controllers as a stack of tupperware containers on your counter top. Each tupperware container will contain a course for a meal.

First thing you put down is your initial view controller.  This is tupperware with a salad.  After enjoying some salad you decide to add the main course so you stack a main course tupperware on top of the salad tupperware.  After this you add a dessert tupperware on top of the main course.  Your stack now contains three tupperware containers.

Now the person is wanting to leave the app/meal so you need to clean up.  You are doing this by trying to pop to a generic tupperware container (new view controller).  Really what you want is to remove the view controllers from the meal to get back to your initial state of a clean counter top with a fresh container of salad.

I used tupperware contains rather than regular plates to emphasis other concerns as you work with the stack. The view controllers will continue to exist as a stack but beware of clean up the operating system may do as you eat.
If you take a long time to eat or your meal is large the OS will clean up your tupperware containers.  They are still there but may not be exactly the way you left them.  So be careful when you return to a tupperware container to verify the contents that are important.  Use the view will appear type methods for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have a better understanding of how VCs work because of your simple explanation. You lost me in the last paragraph though. You're saying that I should put something in my viewWillAppear func?